# How to create id using expression with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, expression

I have a directive with the following code as the template:

```
<video id="{{id}}" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto">
</video>
```

The problem is that the id is not being evaluated.

How can make the angular eval the expression for the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with ngAttr directive (ng-attr-id) to prevent this kind of situation. It let angular create the original attribute at the right time

See : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive